# Mac OSX - IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable:

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Im new to Mac OSX. Downloaded my Robotframework(Selenium & Java) project from git and tried to execute the code locally wherein I received the below error.

Suite setup failed:
IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /Users/roja/Documents/GitHub/testautomation/chromedrivers/chromedriver_osx

To rectify this issue, I followed the below but it didnt work.

> 1. Upgraded the selenium-java and standalone version from 2.53.1 to 3.4.0.
> 2. Driver path specified to Users/roja/automation
> 3. Chromedriver upgraded from 2.31 to 2.33
> 4. And the same driver version updated even in the path specified in the exception above.

Also Im unsure why the path is defaulted to `/Users/roja/Documents/GitHub/testautomation/chromedrivers/chromedriver_osx`. 
My git projects are saved in the path usr/local/git/testautomation and chromedriver also saved in the same. please clarify and provide me a solution.

Below code written for launching the browser,

```
public void LaunchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/roja/Automation/chromedriver_osx");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Quick installation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#quick-installation) of the latest ChromeDriver

To install the latest version of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327):

- **Mac users with Homebrew**:

  ```
  brew tap homebrew/cask && brew cask install chromedriver
  ```

---

### *Original answered Nov 15 '17 at 12:04*

The error `IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /Users/roja/Documents/GitHub/testautomation/chromedrivers/chromedriver_osx` says it all. You have to make exactly 4 changes as follows :

- Change `Webdriver.chrome.driver` as :

  ```
  webdriver.chrome.driver
  ```
- Change `/Users/roja/Automation/chromedriver_osx` as we need to include the name of the `webdriver binary` i.e. **`chromedriver`** as a **`value`** :

  ```
  /Users/roja/Automation/chromedriver_osx/chromedriver
  ```
- Change `driver = new ChromeDriver();` as :

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  ```
- Remove unwanted `throws InterruptedException` to keep your code short and simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DebanjanB . Followed the 1st change and it worked. Such a silly i did. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Nice expalination @DebanjanB +1

Comment: For all those who are struggling with 'cask' not found, use ```brew install --cask chromedriver```

Answer (score 5):

FYI I had to do the solution proposed by varunrao321: Navigate to the folder containing chromedriver and run `chmod +x chromedriver`

Answer (score 5):

I tried giving full permission to the chromedriver and it works fine.

```
chmod +x chromedriver
```

or

```
chmod 777 chromedriver
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that worked for me. 
Navigate to the folder containing chromedriver and run 
"chmod +x chromedriver"

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me as well:

Step 1: Open terminal
Step 2: Navigate to the path folder containing `chromedriver`
Step 3: Run `chmod +x chromedriver`

Answer (score 0):

@debanjan already explain good expalaination to you, I am just giving you correct code:

```
public void LaunchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/roja/Automation/chromedriver_osx/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the permission access. Download the chrome driver using http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and then give path.

Example:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/xyz/Downloads/chromedriver");
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem was by importing the chromedriver with right click>Import instead of dragging it to the folder.

I don't know exactly why, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the last driver that was not working with the chrome version installed on my macOS mojave. I was forced to install last version of google chrome, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may install chromedriver by brew

```sh
brew cask install chromedriver
```

After that, as DebanjanB said, replace your

> System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/roja/Automation/chromedriver_osx");

with

```sh
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One More Solution :

1. Visit : https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSzR6.png)
2. Under "Current Releases" section, Click on Chrome driver link which is updated in your system.
3. Automatically it will redirect to "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path="
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXTPc.png)
4. Click on link for mac and unzip the folder.
5. Now paste chromedriver.exe file into your project.
6. And provide below mentioned code-

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

   public class SetChromeDriver {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/chromedriver");
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
           driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
           driver.quit();

       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the folder where `chromedriver` is present: `chmod +x chromedriver`