# Why doesn't ChromeDriver require Chrome or Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

ChromeDriver is working on my system even though I don't have Chrome or Chromium installed. Based on the name, I thought it was like a "car driver" where you still need a car to get going. Or maybe like a product's API where you still need the product for your API calls to accomplish something.

Edit: Whoops, Chromium is installed after all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course **ChromeDriver** requires **Chrome** or **Chromium**.

As per [**ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) ChromeDriver is a separate executable that WebDriver uses to control Chrome.

Now, as per [**Requirements - ChromeDriver**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements) the server expects you to have **Chrome** installed in the default location for each system as follows:

[image: Chrome_binary_expected_location.png]

<sub><sup>1</sup>For Linux systems, the **ChromeDriver** expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary.</sub>

You can also force ChromeDriver to use a custom location by setting a special capability. You can find the documentation in [**Using a Chrome executable in a non-standard location**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location)

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. Chromium was installed and I missed it somehow. I was having trouble finding these requirements on the ChromeDriver page (they're under "Setup"), plus a co-worker was saying Chrome/Chromium shouldn't be required.