# bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99) error while executing Selenium based automation test in server

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, katalon-studio, webui

I have code for web ui automation test created with Katalon, I have tried to run it locally and it worked well. 
Then I push my code to server but when I run it from server, it failed. It failed to open the web/url that i want. 
I generate the code to execute test from server but when I run that code this is happened :
[image]

bind failed

then it kept loading the browser until it timed out :
[image]

Can anyone suggest/comment or help with a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
[SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to bind the *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Initiating [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) with `--verbose` flag would have helped to debug the issue in a better way.

---

### Solution

As per the documentation in [[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address when starting Dockerized web app](https://medium.com/@simicode/oserror-errno-99-cannot-assign-requested-address-when-starting-dockerized-web-app-54c11f7041ea) the probhable cause and the solution would be to:

1. Close all processes that may be running on your port number. Assuming you are running on port 8000:

   ```
   lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9
   ```
2. You are probably using an app adress as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and you need to change it to `0.0.0.0`
3. Another possible reason can be, [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) attempted to listen on IPv6 address, which was not enabled. You can either enable IPv6 support (which works only on Linux host) or ignore the error since *ChromeDriver* process will be listening on IPv4 after initial failed attempts.