# How to close Headless Firefox after test execution using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, headless

I've been following [this](https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/) tutorial to learn how to use Selenium and I just successfully ran the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

opts = Options()opts.headless=True
assert opts.headless # Operating in headless mode
browser = Firefox(options=opts)browser.get('https://bandcamp.com')
browser.find_element_by_class('playbutton').click()
```

How do I ensure the headless Firefox is no longer running? I ran this code twice and now two songs are playing over each other. Any help is appreciated, I just want to make sure nothing is running in the background!

Answer (score 3):

Irespective of GUI based browser or [headless](/questions/tagged/headless) browser, at the end of your test execution you should always invoke `browser.quit()` which calls the `/shutdown endpoint` and subsequently the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance and the *Browsing Context* both are destroyed completely closing all the pages/tabs/windows.

So your effective code block will be:

```
# previous lines of code
browser.find_element_by_class('playbutton').click()
browser.quit()
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)

---

However, in the rarest of the rare cases there may be residue instances of *WebDriver* e.g. [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) occupying the memory, in those cases you need to kill them with brute force before triggering the next test execution as follows:

- Python Solution (Windows):

  ```
  import os

  os.system("taskkill /f /im geckodriver.exe /T")
  os.system("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe /T")
  os.system("taskkill /f /im IEDriverServer.exe /T")
  ```
- Python Solution (Cross Platform):

  ```
  import os
  import psutil

  PROCNAME = "geckodriver" # or chromedriver or IEDriverServer
  for proc in psutil.process_iter():
      # check whether the process name matches
      if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
      proc.kill()
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial you shared:

> Everything seems to be working. In order to prevent invisible headless
>   browser instances from piling up on your machine, you close the
>   browser object before exiting your Python session:

Try to do the following to see if your issues are fixed:

```
browser.close()
quit()
```

**EDIT:**

Let's straight this out. So based on your request, we currently have:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver # you need this to terminate program 

options = Options() 
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get('https://bandcamp.com')

driver.find_element_by_class('playbutton').click()

ch = input('Do you want to quit the program y/n?')
if ch == 'y':
    driver.quit()
    print('The program is terminated')
```

Let me know if the solution doesn't work

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that I tried running the program with that at the end of it to no avail - Firefox is still open/running.

Comment: In that case, you need `driver` to terminate the program. I will edit it accordingly. @Christina

Comment: @Christina let me know if the edited still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
browser.close()
```

Also you can check the process list (e.g. lsof in Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You can add add `browser.close()` to close the active tab and `browser.quit()` to closes all browser windows and ends driver's session/process.