# Can we cast RemoteWebDriver to ChromeDriver?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I am initializing ChromeDriver on selenium grid using RemoteWebdriver, then I need to cast RemoteWebDriver to ChromeDriver?

If it is possible, can I have an example?

Answer (score 1):

`ChromeDriver` is the extension of `RemoteWebDriver`. If the actual object that is referred by `RemoteWebDriver` is a `ChromeDriver` you can use explicit casting.

Otherwise you will fail to cast since under `RemoteWebDriver` some other extension might take the place (for example `FirefoxDriver` also can be refered as `RemoteWebDriver`) which might not adhere the contract `ChromeDriver` implies (the same is applicable to a pure `RemoteWebDriver` - the object simply does not contain the part that is specific for `ChromeDriver`).

Comment: Can you please provide working example of devtools with RemoteWebDriver?

Answer (score 1):

Till [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) *v3*, [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) extends RemoteDriver. This *ChromeDriver* was a [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) implementation that controled the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser running on the local machine.

However, [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) unleashes a new design/feature where,

- *ChomeDriver* extends to *ChromiumDriver* and
- *ChromiumDriver* extends *RemoteDriver*

As an example to intercept the *Network* you can do the following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
DevTools devTool = driver.getDevTools();
devTool.createSession();
devTool.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
devTool.send(Network.setBlockedURLs(ImmutableList.of("*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.css")));
driver.get("https://amazon.in/b?node=1375424031");
```

Answer (score 0):

We have not need to cast Drivers, we have only need to initialise the WebDriver variable it can handle all the different type of driver.

```
WebDriver driver = null;
if (grid)
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("localhost:4444"));
else
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Augmenter](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/Augmenter.html) mechanism for instance [DevTools](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/#emulate-geo-location-with-the-remote-webdriver)