# Website navigates to no-access page using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium probably Bot Protected

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, akamai

My target site is https://www.nike.com/kr/ko_kr
When using selenium driver.get to connect to this target using webdriver.Chrome().get, the connection is done.

But if I click elements to use my hand or *element_find_xpath()*, it redirected no-access page(probably bot protector) and I cant do anything(other target's sub page etc...).

I changed user-agent, ip but it redirected no-access too.
How can I cheat the site and enable normal access?

I have also changed the user-agent and etc.. But didn't work

Snapshot of code trials:

[image: Change user-agent and etc.. But didnt work]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set a timeout of a few seconds between your actions, to act more "human-like".

There is an implicit and an explicit way (source: [Selenium Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)).

An **explicit** wait is a code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code. The extreme case of this is time.sleep(), which sets the condition to an exact time period to wait

You are probably looking for the **implicit** way: An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

Another way to wait for a few seconds works with the package time:

```
import time 
time.sleep(5) #wait 5 seconds
```

Comment: i set a timeout 10 seconds, but it Still the same

Answer (score 0):

I made some tweaks to your code and executed the test as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver 

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.naver.com/")
  driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
  driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', {get: function() {return[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}})")
  driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'languages', {get: function() {return['ko-KR', 'ko']}})")
  driver.execute_script("const getParameter = WebGLRenderingContext.getParameter;WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.getParameter = function(parameter) {if (parameter === 37445) {return 'NVIDIA Corporation'} if (parameter === 37446) {return 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti OpenGL Engine';}return getParameter(parameter);};")
  driver.get("https://www.nike.com/kr/ko_kr/")
  ```

---

### Observation

Similar to your observation, I have hit the same roadblock being redirected to **No Access** page as follows:

[image: nike_error_no-access]

---

### Deep Dive

It seems [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) initiated *Chrome Browsing Context* is getting detected as a **automated bot**.

Meanwhile, while inspecting the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the *webpage* it was observed that some of the `<script>` tag contains the keyword **akam**. As an example:

- `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.nike.com/akam/11/43465b03" defer=""></script>`
- `<noscript><img src="https://www.nike.com/akam/11/pixel_43465b03?a=dD1kMjkzYzhlOTA4OWVmZTlhOGZhMjg2MjBmNjk5YWVjZmM0Y2U2NWY5JmpzPW9mZg==" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -999px; top: -999px;" /></noscript>`
- `<link id="dnsprefetchlink" rel="dns-prefetch" href="//gerxi63iifbfuxxtmreq-f-e92349eda-clientnsv4-s.akamaihd.net">`

Which is a clear indication that the website is protected by [**Bot Manager**](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/security/bot-manager.jsp) an advanced bot detection service provided by [**Akamai**](https://www.akamai.com/) and the response gets **blocked**.

---

### Bot Manager

As per the article [Bot Manager - Foundations](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/akamai/akamai-bot-manager-training-overview-and-agenda.pdf):

[image: akamai_detection]

---

### Conclusion

So it can be concluded that the request for the data is detected as being performed by [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance and the response is blocked.

---

### References

A couple of documentations:

- [Bot Manager](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/product-brief/bot-manager-product-brief.pdf)
- [Bot Manager : Foundations](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/akamai/akamai-bot-manager-training-overview-and-agenda.pdf)

---

### tl; dr

A couple of relevant discussions:

- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191)