# python webdriver_manager chrome custom profile

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

How can I make webdriver_manager.chrome to use a custom chrome user profile?

I know for selenium webdriver I can specify like this:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={script_path}\\User Data\\profile')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=f'{script_path}\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

But since I want to let chromedriver install the correct version on its own (because I sell my program to non python users) I am using the webdriver_manager module which looks like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Is there any way I could load a custom profile so that my log in data on websites is getting saved in my profile while using webdriver_manager?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [webdriver_manager.chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741852/why-isnt-the-chromedriver-executable-in-the-path-even-after-using-chromedrive/62742262#62742262) and [custom chrome user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195) simultanously using the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={script_path}\\User Data\\profile')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Comment: `executable_path` is deprecated but [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/6243352) shows the way forward!