# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timeout' using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, typeerror

I am trying to scrape a webpage using selenium, and cannot manage to setup the Chrome driver correctly. When running the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe")
```

I get returned the following error:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe")
<ipython-input-71-d74aff86551f>:1: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\bayes\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 142, in _validate_timeout
    float(value)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timeout'
```

I have not found any other similar issue online. Does anyone have a clue what's going on? Thank you!

Comment: Can you check with this? PATH = r"your path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

Comment: try to pass service object, error is all about ` DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object`

Comment: Also, `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timeout'` - have you shared all the code that you've  ?

Comment: Yes, the code is all there. Also, I have just tried to add Service in this way: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(path), options=webdriver.ChromeOptions())`, following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python), but with no luck.

Comment: @yuxuan  I am also getting warning but it's not affecting the execution. did you check what I shared on my first comment?