# DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object what should i do?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import datetime as dt
import urllib.parse
```

I ran this orders.. and I've got these warning.. What should I do?

> C:\Users\jinwoo\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5340/2973355007.py:2: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
> browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:/Users/jinwoo/geckodriver.exe',firefox_binary=binary)
> C:\Users\jinwoo\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5340/2973355007.py:2: DeprecationWarning: firefox_binary has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
> browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:/Users/jinwoo/geckodriver.exe',firefox_binary=binary

Answer (score 1):

`executable_path` option is no longer supported in Selenium 4.

You need to provide path for `chromedriver.exe` as below:

```
# Imports required
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service= Service("path to chromedriver.exe"))
```

[You can also refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64719359/16452840)

Comment: umm.. i would like to use Firefox.. cause i am crawlig twitter

Comment: @hey try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71628814/12281892

Comment: I can't add an answer since it's close but another workaround is `webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(r'path/to/your/geckodriver'))`