# Webdriver call with executable path deprecated

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

When I run my Selenium 4.1 script in Python 3.10, I get a warning
message that the keyword argument `executable_path` is deprecated.
See script below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

edge_path = 'edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=edge_path)
driver.get('https://bing.com')

element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'sb_form_q')
element.send_keys('WebDriver')
element.submit()

time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Warning message:

```
script.py:13: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated,
please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=edge_path)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DeprecationWarning: executable\_path has been deprecated selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, import the `Service` class for the Edge webdriver
(line 4 below), then create a service object with the executable
path (line 7 below).
Subsequently, pass the service object as a keyword argument
to webdriver creation call (line 8 below).

The sample script becomes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

edge_path = 'edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe'
service = Service(executable_path=edge_path)
driver = webdriver.Edge(service = service)
driver.get('https://bing.com')

element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'sb_form_q')
element.send_keys('WebDriver')
element.submit()

time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```