# Why does this Selenium code does not work using Python while trying to target login

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, selenium4

I am trying to target this bit of code to click a login button

```
<button class="Global_PrimaryButton__30J6x Login_SubmitButton__3cJYV" type="submit">Login</button>
```

This is my python code

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://uplearn.co.uk/login")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.LINK_TEXT,"Login"))
element.click()
```

And the error I get is:

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.LINK_TEXT,"login"))
TypeError: presence_of_element_located() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code block as follows:

- [executable_path has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447) and using *Selenium v4.x* you have to pass a *`Service`* object instead.
- Expected Conditions like *`presence_of_element_located()`* needs to be constructed as tuples.
- Ideally, to click on a ***clickable*** element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447).
- Finally, *`Login`* is not the innerText of any `<a>` tag, but of a `<button>` tag, hence *`LINK_TEXT`* won't work and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

Your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

s = Service('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get('https://uplearn.co.uk/login')
# using CSS_SELECTOR
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='Login_SubmitButton']"))).click()
# using XPATH
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Login']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a pair of parenthesis.
Instead of

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.LINK_TEXT,"Login"))
```

It should be

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,"Login")))
```

Also, I'd suggest using `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located` and `CSS_SELECTOR` or `XPATH` instead of `LINK_TEXT`, as following:

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[type='submit']")))
```