# Advice for CSS selection and XPATH selection in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

`<div data-tour="subsection-id-18" class="sc-jUosCB grKglT">`

Im struggling to write the correct CSS selctor for my selenium program can someone give me adive on where to learn the correct paths, as i dont want to keep asking.

`first = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[@class='grKglT']")))`
`first.click()`

What am i doing wrong long and what docs should i look at to help me in the long term

Comment: _can someone give me adive on where to learn the correct paths_: Did you get some time to go through the details of one of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71503453/7429447) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71503227/7429447)? You can have a look at the embedded link for ***locator strategies***

Comment: //div[@data-tour='subsection-id-10'] could also work

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Would it be div. sc-jUosCB grKglT for the CSS SELECTOR