# Fixing Selenium Error: "target frame detached"?

Tags: python, selenium

hope I have provided enough information here. Getting the following error (that worst of all, seems to be happening randomly, regardless of code changes):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00E57413+2389011]
    Ordinal0 [0x00DE9F61+1941345]
    ...
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

PATH = r"C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Project\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(WEBLINK)

search_Hours = driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value="Hours")
search_Hours.click()
time.sleep(3)
tech = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='techStudiesInnerWrap')
print(tech.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

tech_Summary = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='techStudiesInnerWrap').find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='summary')
print(tech_Summary.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
print(tech_Summary.text)
```

I suspect it has something to do with version of Chrome webdriver or perhaps the Depreciation Warning I am getting (see below). But the randomness of it has me stumped.

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

Chrome Browser:
Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)

ChromeDriver:
ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60

There is a slight version mismatch here, but the exact driver doesn't seem to exist for my Chrome Browser.

EDIT:
If it helps anyone, I just switched to Firefox web driver. Problem solved.

Comment: Which line of code raises the error? Can you provide the relevant part of the page html?

Answer (score 0):

Once the key `executable_path` is deprecated you have to use an instance of the `Service()` class as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('C:/Users/.../chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

for more information follow: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python)