# How to fix Deprecation Warning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new to coding and Python - The scraper starts off well and works, until at some point (after around 1 minute or so) it stops and hands out this error message.

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Apparently it refers to line 71 in the code, where the scraper should get item descriptions.

It's based around BeautifulSoup and Selenium:

````
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import csv

        description = productSoup.find('div', id=['desc_div'])
        if description:
            description = description.find('iframe')['src']
            driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
            driver.get(description)
            time.sleep(5)
            description_page = driver.page_source
            driver.quit()
            descriptionSoup = BeautifulSoup(description_page, 'html.parser')
            description = descriptionSoup.find('div', id=['ds_div'])
        else:
            description = 'NA'```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwppg.png
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DeprecationWarning: executable\_path has been deprecated selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python)

Answer (score 1):

change the line

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
```

to

```
s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

Comment: I just tried that, but it then tells me that "Service" is not defined and "ChromeDriverManager" is not defined. Do I need to install additional libraries?

Comment: @FrankF: Please check the mentioned post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python

Comment: @HedgeHog thanks a lot, I already did. It seems like the main issue is now solved, but the scrape runs into another problem. I have added an image of the error.

Comment: @FrankF: This other issue would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus