# Chromedriver added to Path but still getting Message: 'chromedriver_win32' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

OS: Windows 11 using WSL2

Issue: I am trying to use selenium for python and have trouble with the location of the chromedriver executable.

1. I downloaded the chromedriver executable from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads in correspondence with the version of chrome I have (v. 103).
2. I unzipped the folder and stored it in the downloads folder of my desktop.
3. I added the folder path where the .exe is located to my PATH in environment variables.

> \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\my_username\chromedriver_win32\

4. I run the following code:

   ```
    # Import
    from selenium import webdriver

    # Create a driver to help scrape the website
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Website wanting to scrape
    website = "https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed"

    # Opens the browser
    driver.get(website)
   ```
5. When I run my py file with this code in the terminal I get this error message:

   ```
    python scraper.py
   ```

> Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

OTHER SOLUTIONS ATTEMPTED

1. Method 2 from https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/

In this case, the folder was not added to the PATH and the same message occurs.

2. The first and second answer in [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

When I try the first answer I get the same message.

When I try the second answer I get:

> KeyError: 'google-chrome'

3. I tried the top voted answer in [DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python)

and get the same:

> KeyError: 'google-chrome'

4. I tried the answer from Mori on Nov 8, 2021 in [DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python) and get

> Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

I've been working at this for around 3 hours with no progress. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 # Import
 from selenium import webdriver

 # Create a driver to help scrape the website

 # Add path
 PATH = "Path/To/Your/Driver"
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

 # Website wanting to scrape
 website = "https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed"

 # Opens the browser
 driver.get(website)
```

Make sure you put the path to the executable file not the folder including it.

Comment: I just tried and I still get the same message "'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH". In PATH, are you saying I include the filename/extension like chromedriver.exe? I also tried with an absolute path and a relative path like "../path/to/folder/chromedriver.exe". Still no luck. Keeps saying I need to add it to PATH.

Comment: Try using this line ```driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))```
This is the only other fix I can think of, keep in mind this only works in Selenium v4

Comment: I tried this one as well in accordance with the answer from enjoi4life411 in this post -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path. I made the additional imports (Service, ChromeDriverManager) and added the code you suggested in your comment. The result is " KeyError: 'google-chrome' "

Answer (score 0):

As you have *...."unzipped the folder and stored it in the downloads folder of my desktop"..*

Ideally your line of code should be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Same message " 'C:\Users\my_username\Downloads\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH ". I also tried it with and without the r at the beginning. Without the r I get "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape". Finally I tried substituting the \ for /. Same result..."executable needs to be in path". One thing I forgot to mention, my username is a Chinese character. Wouldn't this be interpreted as a string though, I don't think it should matter.

Comment: You just need to replace `username` with your actual (Chinese character based) username. Keep the other things intact.

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.