# get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' error using Selenium 4.3.0 and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, get, selenium-chromedriver

I used to have a script to access to websites, the thing is that one day stoppe working because this error: **"executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object"**. So, I updated Selenium and update the script too:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

service = Service(executable_path="C:/Users/XXXXX/chromedriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Chrome
browser.get(url='https://XXX.sis.ad.bia.XXX/XXX/pages/login.xhtml')
```

Now I got this error:

```
get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I know is a simply error but I cannot solve it.

P.s: the XXX are just for confidentiality

Update:
When I tried this:

```
service = Service(executable_path="C:/Users/fer14538/chromedriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)`
browser = webdriver.Chrome
```

I got this error:

```
Ordinal0 [0x0043F8D1+2029777]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7534FA29+25]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77487A9E+286]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77487A6E+238]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome
```

You need to invoke the `Chrome()` method passing the **service** object and simply pass the *`url_string`* as an argument to `get()` as follows:

```
service = Service("C:/Users/XXXXX/chromedriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
browser.get('https://XXX.sis.ad.bia.XXX/XXX/pages/login.xhtml')
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447)

Comment: I've tried that and got an error, updated in the question.

Comment: Remove the third line i.e. `browser = webdriver.Chrome`

Comment: I still having the same issue on this line: `browser = webdriver.Chrome(service = service)`

Comment: There was a issue with the code which I have addressed now. Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I checked the discussion you mentioned and realize that the chromedriver wasn't updated, now the chrome version and the chromedriver match. Thank you so much!!!