# I am facing trouble launching the browser in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, parameter-passing

**This is what I wrote below. I am using PyCharm 2022.2.2 (Community Edition)**

**Build #PC-222.4167.33, built on September 15, 2022**

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Chrome driver = Path
#to open an URL in a BROWSER

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
name = "Trainer"
service_obj = Service(r"C:\Users\DS-02\Desktop\Manjit\chromedriver.exe")   #---- doesn't works
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Service = service_obj) 



The error which I am getting is below:

C:\Users\DS-02\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe C:\Users\DS-02\Desktop\Manjit\PythonSelenium\Class_1_demo_Browser.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DS-02\Desktop\Manjit\PythonSelenium\Class_1_demo_Browser.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(Service = service_obj)  #----- doesn't works
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Service'


Please help,
Thanks and regards
```

I have tried the code below and works sometime now it doesn't works. I want to fix the code above:

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = service_obj)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '../Webdriver/chromedriver.exe')

Please help

Comment: If you are using selenium 3 than upgrade it to 4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line `driver = webdriver.Chrome(Service = service_obj)` to be

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service_obj)
```

Parameter to be passed into `webdriver.Chrome()` in order to initialize `driver` object should be lowercased **service** while *Service* in your code is this:
`selenium.webdriver.chrome.service`, you called it `Service` here:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Service'
```

...implies that when the program execution starts the `int()` method counters an unexpected keyword argument 'Service'.

---

### Details

With the availability of [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) the key [`executable_path()` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447) and you have to use the key `service`.

However you need to take care of couple of things as follows:

- Incase you use the `service` keyword you have to create a `Service` object and assign the absolute location of the ChromeDriver, you have to import:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  ```
- The keyword within `webdriver.Chrome()` is ***`service`***. So you have to:

  ```
  service_obj = Service('C:\\Users\DS-02\\Desktop\\Manjit\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service_obj)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late to reply to this question, but it worked for me as follows:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("executable_path="+str(path_to_chromedriver))

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

I hope this saves someone if the same problem is encountered!