# AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process' error using Opera browser with Selenium and Python3

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4, operadriver

I'm using the latest version of Opera - version 95.0.4635.46 (x86_64), which is based on Chromium version:109.0.5414.120 and chrome driver version 109.0.5414.74.

When I run the following code on macOS:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opera_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opera_options.binary_location = "/Applications/Opera.app/Contents/MacOS/Opera"
opera_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
opera_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
opera_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
opera_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
opera_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver')
opera_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=opera_options)

time.sleep(3)
# opera_driver.execute_script("window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'")
opera_driver.get("https://www.google.com")
time.sleep(10)
opera_driver.quit()
```

It just opens Opera browser without visiting the provided link for google. What's the reason for that? I've tried everything found on the web including adding intentional sleep and trying `opera_driver.execute_script` but every time the browser starts with the following text in url bar: `data:,`

---

### Update

I tried to use opera-drvier latest release (https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases) which is supposed to fix this issue (as its based on chrome driver and made specifically for opera-specific functionality), but when I run my code I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

...implies that [executable_path has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447) instead you have to pass in a Service object as follows:

```
opera_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opera_options.binary_location = "/Applications/Opera.app/Contents/MacOS/Opera"
...
s = Service('./chromedriver')
opera_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opera_options)
```