# Selenium is randomly killed on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, webdriver-manager

I am working on a Streamlit app that runs properly locally, but when I initiate the web scraping process with multiple threads, the website freezes and the process is killed. The logs in the console indicate the links are being scraped, so I am not sure what is causing the issue. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
2023-02-20 19:50:11.308 Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome 110.0.5481
2023-02-20 19:50:11.310 Driver [/home/ubuntu/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/110.0.5481/chromedriver] found in cache
```

[image]

multithreading func:

```
 threads = []
        for i in links:
            t = threading.Thread(target=get_links, args=(i, resumeContent))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) and [executable_path has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447) and you have to pass in a *`Service`* object.

So effectively, instead of:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

you need to pass:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

so once the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) is downloaded, it can be reused.

---

### Update

As per your question update, as you implemented *`Threading`*, the number of threads you are trying to spawn will always be a matter of concern provided you have only ***2 GB*** of memory.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Something interesting I noticed is that I had a function that used multi threading to run a function. When I changed that to a simple for loop (which takes 10x longer obviously) I didn't see that error anymore. You think the machine kills the process because it's too heavy for the t2.small tier?

Comment: @Mansidak Possibly it does have a domino effect.

Comment: I just tried your solution and still getting the same error. I'm suspecting it's the machine. You think it'll be worth it to try upgrading to a higher tier one just for testing? I wonder why despite having a 2gb memory already a simple multi threaded function is freezing the server.

Comment: @Mansidak Ah, _`2gb`_ isn't enough for _multi threading_ atleast.

Comment: When I ran it on streamlit, it ran like a breeze and they only have me 1gb lol

Comment: Also, I might be mis-using the term multithreading. The code I'm referring to is this where get_links function opens a browser for each link in links :  threads = []
            for i in links:
                t = threading.Thread(target=get_links, args=(i, resumeContent))
                threads.append(t)
                t.start()
            for t in threads:
                t.join()

Comment: Just edited the question for cleaner reference

Comment: @Mansidak Ofcoarse you are using _Threading_ and the number of threads you are trying to spawn will always be a matter of concern provided you have only _2 GB_ of memory.

Comment: Lol just tried upgrading to t2.large with 8gb and it worked.