# Issue running selenium python script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

sorry for the silly question, but I'm trying to run a very simple python script using selenium. Heres the script I have,

```py
from selenium
import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/usr/local/caskroom/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

its giving me the following error,

```
 from selenium
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've installed selenium, and chrome driver so not sure what the problem is, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A linebreak there isn't valid. `from selenium import webdriver`, on the same line.

Comment: Thanks Zac, that worked, the script runs, however I'm getting a warning DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/usr/local/caskroom/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")

Comment: @newb81 check out the [migration docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/) for how to adjust for Selenium 4, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/5774952) with more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
# import required modules
from selenium import webdriver
 
# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # create object
    edgeBrowser = webdriver.Edge(r"msedgedriver.exe")
 
    # open browser and navigate to facebook
    edgeBrowser.get('https://www.facebook.com')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).