# Python Selenium using wrong version of chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want it to use the chromedriver in `/usr/local/bin`

```
from selenium import webdriver


CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)

driver.get('https://scrapingclub.com/')

driver.quit()
```

I don't see why it isn't respecting the path I am passing in

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69892580/4935162