# Selenium Webdriver init Problem in Google Collab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I use this shell in Google Colab,

```
%%shell
# Ubuntu no longer distributes chromium-browser outside of snap
#
# Proposed solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap

# Add debian buster
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list <<'EOF'
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
EOF

# Add keys
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DCC9EFBF77E11517
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 112695A0E562B32A

apt-key export 77E11517 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg
apt-key export 22F3D138 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg
apt-key export E562B32A | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg

# Prefer debian repo for chromium* packages only
# Note the double-blank lines between entries
cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/chromium.pref << 'EOF'
Package: *
Pin: release a=eoan
Pin-Priority: 500


Package: *
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 300


Package: chromium*
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 700
EOF

# Install chromium and chromium-driver
apt-get update
apt-get install chromium chromium-driver

# Install selenium
pip install selenium
```

then I run this code block

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
service = Service(executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get("url")
```

and I got this error

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 14>()
12
13
---> 14 driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
15 driver.get("url")
16

TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got multiple values for argument 'options'

Answer (score 0):

Below line is not correct:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
```

Change it to:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) you have to use the [***Service***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447) keyword. Additionally if you want to add the arguments you have to call `add_argument()` method on the `ChromeOptions()` instance which is *`options`* and assign it to the `option` keyword.

---

### Solution

Implementing the above mentioned tweaks your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service(r'/usr/bin/chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get("url")
```

Comment: When I tried this block I get.

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6a390e54c296> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
      8 options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
----> 9 driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
     10 driver.get("https://www.sprintsandsneakers.com/en/")

TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'