# Selenium 4.6 for Python doesn't like it's own syntax for finding element by ID

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For years I have used `driver.find_element_by_id('foo')`. Company did a computer refresh and the newer version (`4.6`) doesn't recognize that syntax. It wants be to use `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')`.

However I either get the error `Undefined name 'By'` or I get `positional argument follows keyword argument`. This happens even if I literally copy and paste the sample usage code within Spyder. The parser flags it before I even run anything.

Comment: Can you edit the question and update your code?

Comment: You will need to update your  `import` statements to include `By`.

Comment: A quick look at [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) would have answered this question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

You just need the above imports statement to get rid of `Undefined name 'By'`

Refer the simple code below for latest syntax:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Log in']").click()
driver.quit()
```

If you are wondering that there is no code to set path for `driver.exe` or `WebDriverManager` is not used to manage browser drivers, that's because starting selenium `v4.6.0`, you no longer need to set the path of `driver.exe`, new tool within selenium known as [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will do the driver management.

Few references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76574264/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774