# How do I initialize Selenium and ChromeDriver without raising a path error?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run this code in Python to verify that Selenium and ChromeDriver work together:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
# Create an instance of ChromeOptions
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# Specify the path to the chromedriver.exe
chrome_driver_path = 'C:\Users\a2\OneDrive\Desktop\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver using the specified path and options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=options)
```

However, it's giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:/f3.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=options)
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

For what it's worth, Chrome and Chromedriver are installed on the same directory.

Comment: You answer is in this error -- *unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'* remove `executable_path=` and rerun your code.

Answer (score 0):

In selenium version `4.10.0` and above, `executable_path` has been deprecated. See below:

[image]

Source - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

**Solution:** You need to use Service class now if you want to use executable_path. Sample code is as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='C:\\..\\<full path>\\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()
```

Having said the above, refer the below answer, you don't really have to worry about setting the `chromedriver.exe` path anymore.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76574264/7598774