# Update Visual Studio test platform to use latest version of Edge browser when using Azure Pipelines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, automated-tests

I'm setting up an Azure DEVOPS pipeline to run automated UI tests. This has mostly been a success apart from one detail.

The Azure Pipelines VM/agent doesn't have the latest MS Edge web browser version available.

Our IT policy dictates we always run the most up-to-date version of Edge, so I must run the latest version on my development machine. This means I must install the latest version of the 'Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver' in the project.

Locally, all tests run fine.

When I run the release with the latest Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver, I get the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of Microsoft Edge WebDriver only supports Microsoft Edge version 119  Current browser version is 118.0.2088.76 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe (SessionNotCreated)
```

I'm running Edge 119.0.2151.42 locally.

I downgraded Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver to 118.0.2088.76 in the project, and now my DEVOPS Tests run as expected on the Azure Pipelines agent/VM, but of course, I can no longer run or debug the tests locally.

Is there a way in the release pipeline to upgrade edge?

I know I can create a dedicated VM and use it instead, but it seems like a waste when the functionality natively exists in Azure.

Is there another way, something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are managing your browser drivers, but am guessing you are manually setting the `edgedriver.exe` path.

If this is true, why don't you let selenium decide which `EdgeDriver` it should use depending on the Edge browser on your system. This way, it will use edge driver `118` in your Azure VM and edge driver `119` in your local system.

And to achieve the above, you just need to make sure you are using latest selenium(`v4.6.0` or above). Use latest(`v4.15`) if possible.

You don't need to set the path/location of `driver.exe`. Code can be as simple as below.

Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
driver.quit()
```

Java code:

```
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
driver.quit();
```

C# Code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
driver.Quit();
```

To know more about [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/), refer links below:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76574264/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/#:%7E:text=TL%3BDR%3A%20Selenium%20Manager%20is,carry%20out%20the%20automation%20process.)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2022, C# (.NET CORE 7). I don't think I can do that? I have to install the correct NUGET package as part of the project. Unless I'm misunderstanding something? 
(I'll update my question)

Comment: Selenium version has nothing to do with the IDE you are using(Visual Studio) or the programming language(C#). Find out which version of selenium is installed at present in your project and just upgrade it.

Comment: I am using 4.15. I've removed the Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver from the project and can see by doing a simple test (like above) it works. Turns out I was using a NuGet package which was unnecessary.