# Why website doesn't load when I use .get method

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I got problem with load page by chromedriver in Selenium.
After running the code , new tab opens but not load page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

"""Parametry drivera"""

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
    path = "C:/Users/10200385/Downloads/chrome-win64/chrome.exe"
    service = Service(path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)
    driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")
    print(driver.title)
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path = "C:/Users/10200385/Downloads/chrome-win64/chrome.exe"
service = Service(path)
```

Above code is not correct. You should set the path of browser driver(i.e. `chromedriver.exe`), not the browser(`chrome.exe`).

Change the code and set the path of `chromedriver.exe` as below:

```
path = "C:/Users/<full path>/chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(path)
```

Having said the above, you don't really have to worry about setting the `chromedriver.exe` path manually if you are using latest selenium. Check below answers to know more.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76574264/7598774

Answer (score 0):

I remove some unnecessary parts of your code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
try:
    driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

According to official documentation https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/
You don't need to initialize Service object