# in the attached code, exeutable path error is being shown

Tags: python, excel, selenium-webdriver

the code attempts to take product name from one column from excel sheet, goes tot he website, enters the product name in the search box, returns the link of the opened new page url into the adjecant column in the excel sheet.

this is the error - WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import openpyxl
import time

excel_file_path = r"C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\nachiket 24\sql\self\healthcareanalyticsproject\sample.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
sheet_name = "Sheet1"  
PN_header = "A"
sheet = wb[sheet_name]

# Find the column index for "PN_header"
for col in sheet.iter_cols(min_col=1, max_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=1):
    for cell in col:
        if cell.value == PN_header:
            PN_index = cell.column 

# Define the path to Chromedriver executable
chromedriver_path = r'C:\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe'

# Set up Selenium WebDriver with the correct executable_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

# Iterate through rows
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    product_name = sheet.cell(row=row, column=PN_index).value

    # Open the search page
    driver.get("mywesbitelink")

    # Find the search box using id attribute
    search_box = driver.find_element("id", "searchQuery")
    
    # Enter the product name
    search_box.send_keys(product_name)

    # Simulate pressing Enter
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # Wait for the search results page to load
    time.sleep(10)  # Adjust the sleep time as needed

    # Get the URL of the resultant page
    result_url = driver.current_url

    # Update the "Link" column with the obtained URL
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=PN_index + 1, value=result_url)

# Save the updated workbook
wb.save(excel_file_path)

# Close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Have a look at: [DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python)