# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH using ChromeDriverManager and Python

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

I tried to fix the above error by check Stackoverflow and other resources from the internet. But I am getting the error.

I have installed the `webdriver_manager` also. But I could not able to run the code.

I am using kubuntu, pycharm.

Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

'''from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())'''

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/selenium_driver/chromedriver.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Below is my error message:

```
/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Test.py


====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 98.0.4758
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 98.0.4758 google-chrome
Driver [/home/halovivek/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/98.0.4758.102/chromedriver] found in cache
/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Test.py:4: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Test.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 4):

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- If at all you are using [**ChromeDriverManager - Webdriver Manager for Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) you don't have to explicitly download the *ChromeDriver* as it automatically gets downloaded.
- If you want to use the downloaded [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) you can avoid using [*ChromeDriverManager - Webdriver Manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742262/7429447)
- Additionally, [executable_path has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447) in [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) and you have to use an instance of *`Service()`*.

---

### Solution

Using [ChromeDriverManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63686340/7429447) you can use the following code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Downloading a specific version of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) you can use the following code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/selenium_driver/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

**Note**: If you are on *Linux* / *MAC O SX* system you need to strip the extension part i.e. *`.exe`* as it is applicable only for [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) platforms.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [Use Selenium with Brave Browser pass service object written in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69981271/7429447)

Answer (score 2):

The error is

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

Solution is:

```
s = Service('/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/selenium_driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Make sure to download latest version of chromedriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)

**Imports:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Have to use them in conjuction since executable path has been depreciated.

Comment: hi below code is working but it closes the browser. i did not give the driver to close the window. It should stay. from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

s = Service('/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/selenium_driver/chromedriver.exe')

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

Comment: @vivek rajagopalan : it should get closed, the last line that you've `driver.get("google.com")` and then there's nothing. It is expected behavior. Either write some more lines of code and just put `time.sleep(5)` and the window should stay stand.