# "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84" when using Chrome v84

Tags: python, macos, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium to open a headless Chrome browser in Python. I am using Chrome v84 and tried both Chromedriver v84 and v83. I am on Mac.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

path = r"path/to/chromedriver.exe"

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path, options=op)
```

I also tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=op)
```

It returned:

```
ValueError: There is no such driver by url http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_64.0.3282
```

I also attempted to add Chromedriver to PATH and could check it was there by `echo $PATH`, but it did not work.

I also tried running `brew cask upgrade chromedriver`, after installing Chromedriver via homebrew, but it would only install Chromedriver v83 and the update command would only return something like "no updates available".

I also tried adding the path of Chromedriver under `/usr/local/bin` by running `sudo nano /etc/paths` in the terminal. Unfortunately, this time it didn't show up when running `echo $PATH`, and as expected the Python script did not run successfully.

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try '--headless' instead of 'headless' and also '--disable-gpu':

`op.add_argument('--headless')`

`op.add_argument('--disable-gpu')`

Comment: Thanks for your input, I’ll be sure to add that into the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome v84 check too if the ChromeDriverManager version you are using match. That error is about unmatched versions between driver and python code interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’ll go and check the version of ChromeDriverManager and see if I can update it.

Comment: Hey, as a follow up, I reinstalled webdrivermanager which I assumed held the latest version of ChromeDriverManager but unfortunately, when running `ChromeDriverManager().install()` it returns saying the link "does not exist", attempting to download version 64 of Chromedriver. Must be an error with webdrivermanager.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ValueError: There is no such driver by url http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_64.0.3282
```

...implies that the your program tried to download and install the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) from the url `http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_64.0.3282` which is incorrect.

The correct url is:

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE
```

which returns:

```
84.0.4147.30
```

Possibly a bug in [webdrivermanager](/questions/tagged/webdrivermanager)

---

### [Quick installation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#quick-installation) of the latest ChromeDriver

To install the latest version of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) you can use:

- **Mac users with Homebrew**: `brew tap homebrew/cask && brew cask install chromedriver`
- **Debian based Linux distros**: `sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver`
- **Windows users with Chocolatey installed**: `choco install chromedriver`

> You can find a detailed iscussion in [session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74 error with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201226/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-7/55201365)

---

### tl; dr

However since yesterday (Jul 15, 2020) `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` returned:

```
83.0.X
```

Which was incorrect. `@John Chen` ensured that we have fixed that now.

Snapshot:

[image: LATEST_RELEASE]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I will definitely try this tomorrow, and follow up.

Comment: Hi, I followed your instructions, however, I continued to receive the same error: `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84`. Any ideas from here? My Chrome browser is v84.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to use exact driver exe  accourding web browser version . go to your browser -->about section and check version of chrome then you can download driver.exe in https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads this link

(Browser version are updating time to time so you need to update your driver versions)