# Unable to execute the chrome driver on Jenkins in Linux

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have jenkins which is running on Linux box and Whenever I tried to run the below script its failing and says the driver is not executable.

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /COMPLIANCE-48/workspace/AutoProfile_Exec/Driver/chromedriver
  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
```

**Code:**

```
        String getLocation=System.getProperty("chromePath");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",getLocation);
        WebDriver iDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

**The below is mvn command**:

```
-U clean compile exec:java -DchromePath="${WORKSPACE}/Driver/chromedriver"
```

Actually I have placed the chromedriver in that specific path and passing it as an argument. But not sure why it's saying driver is not executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In linux and mac machines, we don't have the exe files like we have in windows so you need to make the driver executable by using the chmod +x command. Please go to the path where chromedriver is present and then execute the chmod +x command.

In your case it should be:

```
cd /COMPLIANCE-48/workspace/AutoProfile_Exec/Driver
chmod +x chromedriver
```

After running the above commands, try to run the code, it would work then.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Sameer Arora answer, if his solution doesn't solve the problem then try to change `-DchromePath` to `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver` like below:

```
-U clean compile exec:java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="${WORKSPACE}/Driver/chromedriver"
```

And make sure that the `chromedriver` is a executable driver file and not a directory or something else.

Check [Mac OSX - IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306190/mac-osx-illegalstateexception-the-driver-is-not-executable) for more information.