# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Mac OS and trying to open the Chrome browser with Selenium, getting this error.

Mac+Java+Selenium+Chromedriver

Comment: Can you share the code where you are getting this error?

Comment: could you share more details like about which selenium version and chromedriver you are using

Comment: This seem's to be duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306190/mac-osx-illegalstateexception-the-driver-is-not-executable

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using a chromedriver that is compatible with your mac version. Then try giving below permission to chromedriver.

`chmod 777 chromedriver`

Answer (score 1):

After downloading chrome driver from "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.140/" for MAC and copy to your mac username folder.

and also try to giving full permission to the chromedriver and it will work fine by following cmd

```
chmod +x chromedriver
```

Please note not to give ".exe" extension, In the code you have to write as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/macusernamefolder/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```